# c# uwp pointer position

Tags: c#, uwp, position, mouse

In UWP I am trying to get position of pointer.

I have managed to do it with next Event:

```
    private void Grid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerPoint point = e.GetCurrentPoint(mainGrid);
        var x = point.Position.X;
        var y = point.Position.Y;
    }
```

And with this way it will be fired all the time. So, I needed some property to get that position. I have found this:

```
var pointerPosition = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerPosition;
```

But it doesn't always return correct position.

Any other property to get current mouse location?

Comment: What you mean by "So, I needed some property to get that position"? Because you have already got your mouse position using above method

Comment: But it will be fired each time I move my mouse.

Comment: So you want the pointer position when a particular function is called. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah. For example, I have some popup, and I am getting it vertical offset. I want to calculate if popup is above or under mouse pointer. And with Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerPosition I don't get correct location.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var pointerPosition = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerPosition;
```

`pointerPosition` gives you the client coordinates which are the cursor position X & Y of the screen, not relative to your app Window.

So you just need to use `Window.Current.Bounds` to find the coordinates of your app Window first, and then -

```
var x = pointerPosition.X - Window.Current.Bounds.X;
var y = pointerPosition.Y - Window.Current.Bounds.Y;
```

Comment: Also `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition` should give you the same client coordinates.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanx :)

Comment: And do you know maybe how to get the current "Holding location" on mobile phone, like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907117/c-sharp-uwp-current-finger-holding-coordinates-on-mobile

Comment: And yes, I am using it. But, I have a problem because it firing after the tooltip is shown, so I don't get the correct information.

Comment: Hmm not sure as I don't have a mobile emulator. But the PointerPosition method doesn't work on mobile?

Comment: Nope, it always show 320 as Y coordinate wherever user touches.

Comment: If there are two pointer touching at sametime, do we still get their info ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add PointerMoved event handlers through code

   ```
   mainGrid.PointerMoved += mainGrid_PointerMoved;
   ```
2. Remove PointerMoved event handlers in the event handler

   ```
   mainGrid.PointerMoved -= mainGrid_PointerMoved;
   ```
3. Then Get the pointer data in PointerMoved event handlers

   ```
   var x = e.GetCurrentPoint(mainGrid).Position.X;
   var y = e.GetCurrentPoint(mainGrid).Position.Y;
   ```

Here is the entire code

```
void GetPointerPosition()
{
    mainGrid.PointerMoved += mainGrid_PointerMoved;
}

void MainStack_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mainGrid.PointerMoved -= mainGrid_PointerMoved;
    var x = e.GetCurrentPoint(mainGrid).Position.X;
    var y = e.GetCurrentPoint(mainGrid).Position.Y;
}
```

Learn more about [Adding event handlers in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#adding-event-handlers-in-code) from here

Answer (score 0):

This works for me at my canvas:

```
 var x = e.GetCurrentPoint(canBackArea).Position.X;
 var y = e.GetCurrentPoint(canBackArea).Position.Y;
```