# c# uwp current finger holding coordinates on mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, touch, coordinates

In C# UWP, how to get current finger holding coordinates on mobile?

I have been using this:

```
    private void mainGridHolding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var coordinateY = e.GetPosition(mainGrid).Y;
    }
```

But, I don't want to execute it all the time whenever user holding the screen.

And also, this event fire after the popup is shown, so I get the wrong informations.

Like there is a property for Pointer location:

```
var pointerPosition = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerPosition;
```

Is there any property that holds the information about current touch?

Comment: `PointerPosition` is the property that holds the information about current touch. Pointer input includes touch, touchpad, mouse, or pen. However, there is no property specified for holding. If you want to get the coordinates, you will have to use holding event.

Comment: Well, for me, PointerPosition always returns 320 for Y. And the problem is that I am doing some logic on Tooltip SizeChange, and the holding event is fire after that.

Comment: you could consider to add or remove the holding event, so it will be only executed when necessary.

Comment: Problem is that Holding event is fire after the SizeChanged event of Tooltip. I need Holding event to fire first.