# PointerMoved event not firing on MapControl when in 3D view

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling, uwp-maps

`PointerMoved` event is not firing when `MapControl` is 3D view, but when back to 2D or zenithal view is firing again.

When on zenithal view, event is fired whenever the mouse is moved over the map control.

When in 3D view, event is only fired when the mouse is moved over some image controls that are placed on the map. Moving over the map doesn't fire the event.

I don't know why is not firing or what is preventing to firing if it is caused by my code (in that case, what can be the cause?).

Comment: After my testing, MapControl doesn’t trigger pointer events. So you could add transparent xaml control over MapControl, then register pointermove events for them. But this way will cause that the event won't get routed properly as it is fired in another UIElement. We have reported this issue to team. More info could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/181829/mapsmapcontrol-pointermoved-event-does-not-fire-on.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the transparent overlay solution causes issues could roll-your-own using a timer and getting the pointer position directly:

```
var pointerPosition = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerPosition;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905071/c-sharp-uwp-pointer-position) for details.

Timer would compute the pointer position delta per tick and if it's above a threshold trigger an event.